# Matrices Math Issues

Tags: c++, matrix, access-violation

```
#include "matrixType.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//Default Constructor to Intialize private members of class
matrixType::matrixType() {

    this->rowSize = 0;
    this->colSize = 0;
    this->matrix=0;

}
//Parameterized Constructor  which performs deep copy of class member variables
//Purpose:- To Store the input into the object of class
//Pre-condition :- Class object is initialized to zero by the default constructor
//Post-condition:- Object is initialized with the parameters
matrixType::matrixType(int rowSize1, int colSize1) {
    cout<<"In Parameterized Constructor";
    this->rowSize = rowSize1;
    this->colSize = colSize1;
    matrix=new int*[rowSize];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rowSize ; i++ )
        matrix[i] = new int [colSize];
}
//Copy constructor  which performs deep copy of class member variables
//Purpose:- To run before any operations on matrices
//Pre-condition :- Resultant matrix is zero
//Post-condition:- We get the resultant Matrix
matrixType::matrixType(const matrixType &matrix2) {
    cout<<"In copy Constructor";
    rowSize = matrix2.rowSize;
    colSize = matrix2.colSize;
    matrix = matrix2.matrix;
}
//Overload outStream << operator
//Purpose:- To show output on screen
ostream& operator<<(ostream&osobj, const matrixType &mat)
{
    cout << "matrix is::" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rowSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.colSize; j++)
        {
            osobj  << mat.matrix[i][j];

        }
        cout << endl;

    }
    return osobj;
}
//Overload instream operator
//Purpose:- To take the input from user

istream& operator>>(istream&isobj, const matrixType &matin)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matin.rowSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matin.colSize; j++)
        {
            isobj >> matin.matrix[i][j];
        }

    }
    return isobj;
}

// member function setMatrix() to read matrix elements from console and initialize
//Purpose:- To read the values of matrices and set them inobject
void matrixType::setMatrix() {
    int c, d;

    cout << "\nEnter the elements of matrix\n";

    for (c = 0; c < rowSize; c++)
        for (d = 0; d < colSize; d++) {
            cin>>this->matrix[c][d];
        }
    cout << "\n\nMatrix :\n\n";
    for (c = 0; c < rowSize; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < colSize; d++) {
            cout <<"\t"<<this->matrix[c][d];
        }
        cout <<"\n\n";
    }
}
//Equal member function to compare the row and column size of matrices for addition and subtraction
bool matrixType::equal(matrixType &h){
    if (this->rowSize==h.rowSize && this->colSize==h.colSize)

        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
//Equate member function to compare the row and column size of matrices for Multiplication
bool matrixType::equate(matrixType &h){
    if (this->colSize==h.rowSize)

        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
//Overloading Assignment Operator
//Purpose:- To perform assigning operations between the objects of class
void matrixType:: operator=(const matrixType &matrix2) const
{
    cout <<"Assign";

    for (int i= 0;i <matrix2.rowSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j< matrix2.colSize;j++)
        {
            matrix2.matrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

}
//Overloading Addition Operator
//Purpose:- To perform addition of two objects
//Pre-condition :- Two class objects of matrixType
//Post-condition:- Output Object that is the sum of two objects
matrixType matrixType:: operator+(const matrixType &matrix2) const
{
    cout <<"Add";
    matrixType matrixSum(rowSize,colSize);
    for (int i= 0;i <matrix2.rowSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j< matrix2.colSize;j++)
        {
            matrixSum.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + matrix2.matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nMatrix :\n\n";
    for (int c = 0; c < rowSize; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < colSize; d++) {
            cout <<"\t"<<matrixSum.matrix[c][d];
        }
        cout <<"\n\n";
    }
    return matrixSum;
}
//Overloading subtraction operator
//Purpose:- To perform subtraction of two objects
//Pre-condition :- Two class objects of matrixType
//Post-condition:- Output Object that is the subtraction of two objects
matrixType matrixType:: operator-(const matrixType &matrix2) const
{
    cout <<"Subtract";
    matrixType matrixSum(rowSize,colSize);
    for (int i= 0;i <matrix2.rowSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j< matrix2.colSize;j++)
        {
            matrixSum.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] - matrix2.matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nMatrix :\n\n";
    for (int c = 0; c < rowSize; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < colSize; d++) {
            cout <<"\t"<<matrixSum.matrix[c][d];
        }
        cout <<"\n\n";
    }
    return matrixSum;
}
//Overloading Multiplication Operator
//Purpose:- To perform multiplication of two objects
//Pre-condition :- Two class objects of matrixType
//Post-condition:- Output Object that is the multiplication of two input objects
matrixType matrixType:: operator*(const matrixType &matrix2) const
{
    cout <<"Multiplication";
    matrixType matrixM(rowSize,colSize);
    for (int i= 0;i <this->rowSize; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0;k< matrix2.colSize;k++)
        {
            matrixM.matrix[i][k]=0;
            for (int j=0;j<matrix2.rowSize;j++){
                matrixM.matrix[i][k] = matrix[i][j] * matrix2.matrix[j][k];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nMatrix :\n\n";
    for (int c = 0; c < rowSize; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < colSize; d++) {
            cout <<"\t"<<matrixM.matrix[c][d];
        }
        cout <<"\n\n";
    }
    return matrixM;
}
//destructor which properly removes any resources and deallocates memory
//Purpose:- To empty the memory used , to make it avaible again
//Pre-condition:- Objects are present in memory
//Post-condition:- Memory is empty after removing resources
matrixType::~matrixType(){
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++)
        delete[] matrix[i];
        delete[] matrix;
}
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work correctly. My problem is i'm getting an access read violation at

```
        matrix2.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
```

Can't seem to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm pretty sure my pointers are off somewhere. And now im just adding more information because it's making me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell without seeing what is inside "matrixType.h" but I've spotted something in your assignment operator.
First, the parameter is a const reference to a matrixType then you assign the content of `matrix` (which is a member of matrixType I assume). that should not happen.
Second, you mixed up that operator. The member `matrix` should be the one being assigned to.